# Load a RPT file into C# windows service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to load a .rpt file which I have putted into my solution.

I am trying to load it as ::

```
        rd.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+(@"\Reports\InvoiceDocument.rpt"));
```

But getting the Problem in this loading. Because the Path given by `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is the Path to 'bin' folder.
But my rpt file is in parent folder.

I know this can be a kind of Basic question but I stucked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rd.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+(@"..\Reports\InvoiceDocument.rpt"));
```

Comment: It returns path as     "c:\\users\\rahul\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\MVCWithWebService_Demo\\WebService_Demo\\bin\\Debug\\\\..\\Reports\\"

which is not right

Comment: Where do you expect to have `Reports` folder in relation to the service .exe file?

Comment: My .rpt file is in                         
c:\\users\\rahul\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\MVCWithWebService_Demo\\WebService_Demo\\Reports\\

Comment: So you need to go two levels up `@"..\..\Reports\InvoiceDocument.rpt"`

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy the application, where the rpt file will be?

If you need to be in the same directory that your executable, then select the rpt file in the solution explorer and, in properties, set the property 'copy to output directory' to *copy always* or *copy if newer*.

Comment: my .rpt file is in the solutions folder itself as::

c:\\users\\rahul\\documents\\visual studio 2013\\Projects\\MVCWithWebService_Demo\\WebService_Demo\\Reports\\

Comment: Yes, but when you deploy the application, your files should be in a relative path to the exe file. That is because you should to set the copy to output directory.
Another way is to put your rpt files in a well known folder, like %appdata%